# ¿Como hacer para no imprimir dos veces el resultado de lo obtenido en un input con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lo que me suce es que al darle al boton total me imprime el resultado de los 4 inputs(1 de nombre y 3 de numeros) colocados y me lo muestra en el dom pero al hacerlo por segunda vez me vuelve a mostrar el primer resultado dos veces mas el nuevo resultado. Mi duda es como tendria que hacer para que no me imprima dos veces el mismo resultado a la segunda vez. Gracias de antemano!

```
btnTotal.onclick = function realizarPromedio(){

    const aprobado = 7

    nombreAlumno = document.getElementById('nom').value

    let nota1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value)

    let nota2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value)
    let nota3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num3').value)
    resultadoNota = Math.round((nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3)

    if(resultadoNota >= aprobado){
        console.log("Nota final de " + nombreAlumno + " es " + resultadoNota + " esta aprobado" )
        swal({
            title: "Bien hecho!",
            text: nombreAlumno + " tu nota es " + resultadoNota + ", estas aprobado!",
            icon: "success",
        });
        baseDatos.push("Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota )
    }else {
        console.log("Nota final de " + nombreAlumno + " es " + resultadoNota + " esta desaprobado" )
        swal({
            title: "Sigue Intentando",
            text: nombreAlumno + " tu nota es " + resultadoNota + ", estas desaprobado!",
            icon: "error",
        });
        baseDatos.push("Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota )
        }

for(const promedio of baseDatos){
    const resultado = document.createElement("li")
    resultado.innerHTML = promedio
    
    divPromedio.appendChild(resultado)

    let total = []
    total.push(baseDatos)
    localStorage.setItem("Promedios", JSON.stringify(total)) }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `for` es lo que te está causando problemas. Me tomé la libertad de simplificar un poco el código, ya que había muchas repeticiones innecesarias:

```
const aprobado = 7

nombreAlumno = document.getElementById('nom').value

const nota1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value)
const nota2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value)
const nota3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num3').value)
resultadoNota = Math.round((nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3)

const estaAprobado = resultadoNota >= aprobado

console.log(`Nota final de ${nombreAlumno} es ${resultadoNota}, esta ${estaAprobado ? 'aprobado' : 'desaprobado'}`)

swal({
    title: estaAprobado ? "Bien hecho!" : "Sigue Intentando",
    text: `${nombreAlumno} tu nota es ${resultadoNota}, estas ${estaAprobado ? 'aprobado' : 'desaprobado'}!`,
    icon: estaAprobado ? "success" : "error",
})

const texto = "Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota
baseDatos.push(texto)

const resultado = document.createElement("li")
resultado.innerHTML = texto

divPromedio.appendChild(resultado)

localStorage.setItem("Promedios", JSON.stringify(baseDatos))
```

Comment: Ahora si! Anda perfecto, muchas gracias!!